# MongoDB - PHP Pub/Sub

Tags: php, mongodb, publish-subscribe

I have a project and i do this project in NodeJS-MongoDB but i want to do this project with PHP language.

In this project I have capped mongodb collection and want to do pub/sub hub with PHP but does not exists anyone document/support for this. Only redis pub/sub examples and support exists. Have you got any idea or information how to do pub/sub with php-mongodb?

Comment: I am sure this has been asked 100 times but I cannot find a duplicate atm, basically you can use tailable cursors to keep alive a connection to the DB that can message you about changes

Comment: thanks for helping but i didn't see any example for pub/sub with php and mongodb. you maybe little more tolerance. and this question maybe related result for researchers of this topic.

Comment: Here is the first Google result on the subject http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29495793738/pubsub-with-mongodb

Comment: Yes but without PHP example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at tailable cursors see here http://jwage.com/post/30490196727/mongodb-tailable-cursors for a php example and the docs http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.tailable.php